# Alias not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, alias

So I have added an alias for jumping to another directory like this

in my ./bashrc file , Looks like this

```
alias crmx="cd /var/www/crm/website-crm/"
```

Then i saved the file

but when I try to run

```
crmx
```

it says

> command not found

Also I tried to do `alias` to see all the command but my command is not listed

Any idea ?

Comment: source the file after you save it. `source bashrc`.The bashrc file's changing don't affect current bash process

Comment: Also in centos it should be .bashrc .Don't know if you save the file with correct name.And also Be aware of the difference between `bashrc` and `bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is `~/.bashrc` (starting with a dot).

And you have to source it (reload) by doing `source ~/.bashrc` or just by closing and reopening your terminal.

You can also type `ps` to check if your shell is bash (for example if it's zsh you have put your alias in the `~/.zshrc` file)

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you are on bash.

Once you saved that file, you have to have bash read it with a command like this:

```
. ~/myaliasfile
```

or like this

```
source ~/myaliasfile
```

if the file resides in your home directory. Specify the path (relative to your home or absolute) otherwise.

Then you'd go to your `.bashrc` file and add the very same line to the end of it. By doing so the alias(es) will be read and made available to every single bash invocation and login.

Done!

More details [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).